# Legend Problem with arcGIS javascript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I am new to arcGIS javascript API.I tried to display a simple dynamic map service with legend but its not displaying legend. I am not able to find error in my code. Please help me in resolving the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://{Myserver}/arcgis_js_api/library/3.7/3.7/js/esri/claro/claro.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://{Myserver}/arcgis_js_api/library/3.7/3.7/js/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
     @import "http://{Myserver}/arcgis_js_api/library/3.7/3.7/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";
      @import "http://{Myserver}/arcgis_js_api/library/3.7/3.7/js/dojo/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
      @import "http://{Myserver}/arcgis_js_api/library/3.7/3.7/js/dojo/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css";
      .zoominIcon { background-image:url(http://{Myserver}/arcgis_js_api/library/3.7/3.7/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/images/nav_zoomin.png); width:32px; height:32px; }
      .zoomoutIcon { background-image:url(http://{Myserver}/arcgis_js_api/library/3.7/3.7/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/images/nav_zoomout.png); width:32px; height:32px; }
      .zoomfullextIcon { background-image:url(http://{Myserver}/arcgis_js_api/library/3.7/3.7/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/images/nav_fullextent.png); width:32px; height:32px; }
      .zoomprevIcon { background-image:url(http://{Myserver}/arcgis_js_api/library/3.7/3.7/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/images/nav_previous.png); width:32px; height:32px; }
      .zoomnextIcon { background-image:url(http://{Myserver}/arcgis_js_api/library/3.7/3.7/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/images/nav_next.png); width:32px; height:32px; }
      .panIcon { background-image:url(http://{Myserver}/arcgis_js_api/library/3.7/3.7/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/images/nav_pan.png); width:32px; height:32px; }
      .deactivateIcon { background-image:url(http://{Myserver}/arcgis_js_api/library/3.7/3.7/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/images/nav_decline.png); width:32px; height:32px; }
    </style>
    <style>
body, html {
    margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width:100%;
}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">djConfig = { parseOnLoad:true }</script>
    <script src="http://{Myserver}/arcgis_js_api/library/3.7/3.7/init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("esri.map");
    dojo.require("esri.dijit.Legend");
    dojo.require("esri.toolbars.navigation");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
    dojo.require("dijit.Toolbar");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");

    var map,navToolbar; 


      function init() {
       map = new esri.Map("map", {
       basemap:"topo",
       zoom:3
      });
      var startExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent(73.955727,  11.490257, 78.632229, 18.627605,
     new esri.SpatialReference({wkid:4326}));
      map.setExtent(startExtent);

       var layer1=new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://{Myserver}/ArcGIS/rest/services/Karnataka_new/MapServer");
        map.addLayer(layer1);


      navToolbar = new esri.toolbars.Navigation(map);
      dojo.connect(navToolbar,"onExtentHistoryChange", extentHistoryChangeHandler);

      dojo.connect(map, "onLayersAddResult", function(results) {
      var legend = new esri.dijit.Legend({
       map:map,
      layerInfos:[{layer:layer1,title:"sample"}],
      },"legendDiv");
      legend.startup();
});

}
     function extentHistoryChangeHandler() {
     dijit.byId("zoomprev").disabled = navToolbar.isFirstExtent();
     dijit.byId("zoomnext").disabled = navToolbar.isLastExtent();
     };
    dojo.addOnLoad(init);
  </script>
 </head>
 <body class="claro">
  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="headline" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0" liveSizing="false">
     <div data-dojo-props="region:'left'" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Legend'" style="width:18%; border:1px solid #000;">
         <div id="legendDiv"></div>
        </div>
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top" style="height:33px; width:100%;"> 
      <div id="navToolbar" data-dojo-type="dijit.Toolbar">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" id="zoomin"  data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoominIcon', onClick:function(){navToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Navigation.ZOOM_IN);}">Zoom In</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" id="zoomout" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoomoutIcon', onClick:function(){navToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Navigation.ZOOM_OUT);}">Zoom Out</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" id="zoomfullext" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoomfullextIcon', onClick:function(){navToolbar.zoomToFullExtent();}">Full Extent</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" id="zoomprev" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoomprevIcon', onClick:function(){navToolbar.zoomToPrevExtent();}">Prev Extent</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" id="zoomnext" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoomnextIcon', onClick:function(){navToolbar.zoomToNextExtent();}">Next Extent</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" id="pan" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'panIcon', onClick:function(){navToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Navigation.PAN);}">Pan</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" id="deactivate" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'deactivateIcon' ,onClick:function(){navToolbar.deactivate();}">Deactivate</div>
   </div></div>
   <div id="map" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center"  style="overflow:hidden;">
   </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>


    enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onLayersAddResult fires after all layers are added to the map using the map.addLayers method.
Change
map.addLayer(layer1);
with:
map.addLayers([layer1]);